# $DetA=0$ Incorrect?

Tags: linear-algebra

Here is the question:
[image]

And the answer:

[image]

The only thing that baffles me is what I've painted in yellow. Those two are linearly dependent (after row elimination the bottom row would be zero), meaning that the determinant of the matrix should be $detA=0$. The answer however says another story?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that answer says "$\det A = 1-1 = 0$."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem is. The answer says that the determinant is $0$, as you also claim. It's just that you arrive at the answer by noting two identical rows, while the quote arrives at the answer by a direct computation of the determinant. My guess is that the quote you give appears very shortly after the definition was given, and that the definition was given in terms of permutations or something of the sort. The exercise is then asking you to use the definition directly, and not resort to more general properties like linear independence of rows/columns etc. I do think though that it would have been better to avoid identical rows.

Comment: I indeed misinterpreted the answer! Your explanation is more than enough!